# Wrap method with inner class in another method

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I want to wrap a method from a library in a global class `DAO.class`
The method contains an inner class.

In the normal activity is it like this:

```
   pathListener = new DbxFileSystem.PathListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPathChange(DbxFileSystem dbxFileSystem, DbxPath dbxPath, Mode mode) {

                DbxSyncStatus status = null;
                try {

                    if(  dbxFs.hasSynced() && !isLocallyChanged()){

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                update();
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                      setLocallyChanged(false); 
                    }
                } catch (DbxException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
 dbxFs.addPathListener(pathListener, new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT,
                "path"), DbxFileSystem.PathListener.Mode.PATH_OR_DESCENDANT);
```

Now i want a method `DAO.addPathListener(String path);` which creates the above code and replaces the "path".

The problem are the methods in the inner class which are from the `MainActivity` and not only from the `DAO.class` itself.

Is there a Design Pattern for this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What stops you from moving this code to the DAO.addPathListener(path) method and simply replacing "path" with the parameter path?

Comment: i wanto to capsle all method wich are from the dropbox api and not from the activity.
so setLocallyChanged and isLocallyChanged should not be by default there.